# How to add a custom and dynamic block during onepage checkout?

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I need to add a custom block dynamically to the onepage checkout process but I am not sure exactly how to implement this.

The problem is that this custom block appears only when the cart contains a certain type of products (eg, software activation licenses) and the user is required the user to input a serial number of his/her hardware device. If there are X number of licenses in the shopping cart, there will be X text fields inside this custom block.

How should I start looking at this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest adding these serial number fields as a required custom options, which is what its designed to be used for.  This would be entered on the product page when the item is added to cart.

This will make your life a lot easier in terms of surfacing this information on the order history, linking it to the product, etc.

A solution customizing a part of the checkout flow to add this info onto the quote, order or order items is going to get complicated quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion seems to work much better. I just tested it and was able to capture the serial numbers.